# Issue with Zip file exports in Ruby / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having an issue with my rails action that takes binary (blob) files from my database and packages them up into a nice zip file and then finally sends it out for download. The problem occurs when I try to unzip the file, it says something like "Unable to expand; Error 1 - Operation not permitted." I believe that means that the file is corrupted but I don't know what I am doing wrong. I've included my code below, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
require 'zip/zip'
require 'zip/zipfilesystem'

def export
  @layers = Layer.where('group_id > 1')
  temp = Tempfile.new("layers-zip-export")
  Zip::ZipOutputStream.open(temp.path) do |zipfile|
    @layers.each do |layer|
      zipfile.put_next_entry(layer.name)
      file = Tempfile.new("temp-" + layer.id.to_s)
      file.binmode
      file << layer.file
      file.rewind
      zipfile.write IO.binread(file.path)
      file.close
      file.unlink
    end
  end

  send_file temp.path, :type => 'application/zip', :filename => "layer-export.zip"
  temp.close
end
```

Comment: hi there.. same issue.. could you figure it out?